# Wait for a multithreading program written in C++ in java

Tags: java, c++, linux, multithreading

I written a program in C++ where multithreading is used. Call this program using a bash script or something like that is no problem, everything is working fine. Now I want to call this program in Java. This is the Java code sample I tried:

```java
Process v2j = new ProcessBuilder("./src/main/cpp/vcd_converter",
                 "-vcd", vcdfilePath, "-out", logfilePath).start();                     

InputStream is = v2j.getInputStream();
InputStream es = v2j.getErrorStream();

for(int i = 0; i < is.available(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Input: " + br.readLine());
}
for(int i = 0; i < es.available(); i++) {
    System.out.println("Error: " + ebr.readLine());
}
                                    
v2j.waitFor();
```

So if I run this code, following will happen: It seems like the `waitFor()` instruction will not realy wait for "all" threads, maybe it will wait only for one. However, the java program executed with a error because it can't find files which are generated by the C++ program. So the `waitFor()` don't wait until my c++ program is finished and has generated the files.

The output is really weird too. I only get one output from `std::cout`. Here's an example:

```cpp
std::cout << out_folder_path << "\n" << vcd_filename << "\n";
std::cout << std::flush;
```

This will print only the `out_folder_path` output. A problem is: In the section of the `std::cout` I don't even use multi-threading. All other `std::cout` in the program are don't printed too.

So my questions: How can I wait for really ALL threads? And how can I get the real output of my program?

Comment: What happens if `is.available()` returns 0 because the C++ program has not printed anything yet? I don't see how this has anything to do with C++ or the threads in the C++ program.

Comment: Ok yes you're right. The problem will caused by the Java program. And `is.available()` don't return 0, it's print the first output of the C++ program.

Comment: `is.available()` doesn't print anything. It "_Returns an estimate of the number of bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream._"

Comment: Yes of course, I mean the `for(int i = 0; i < is.available(); i++) {
        System.out.println("Input: " + br.readLine());
    }` instruction print the first C++ output.

Comment: So, again, what happens if `is.available()` returns 0 becase the C++ program has not printed anything when you reach that line?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question, I think.

Comment: Your question is about why the java program does not wait for all C++ threads to finish and why you don't get all the output from the C++ program. I'm trying to make you look at what your java program is doing. It checks if there is anything available to read and if there isn't, it will jump to the `waitFor()`. What your java program _should_ be doing is to read from the input stream until the input stream closes.

Comment: Okay.. if i add `while((is.available() == 0)) {System.out.println("Input: " + br.readLine()); v2j.waitFor();}` , then the first two statements will be printed.. but that's all what changed.

Comment: Don't use `available()` at all. It tells you if something is available *right this instant*. If something is printed 10ms from now your program will get tripped up. Avoid the method entirely. You want to call something that will *block and wait* if there's no input available at the moment. Ted's answer does that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program doesn't get all output from the C++ program because it doesn't read until the input streams are depleted. It jumps to `waitFor` if the C++ program has not produced any output when your program reaches `is.available()`.

Here's an alternative approach doing reading until the input streams are closed. It uses an `InputStreamReader` and a `BufferedReader` and calls the `BufferedReader`'s `readline()` until the input stream closes.

<sub>Disclaimer. I haven't written any java programs before so I'm not sure I've gotten everything correct. The general idea should work though.</sub>

```
var v2j = new ProcessBuilder("./src/main/cpp/vcd_converter", "-vcd", 
                             vcdfilePath, "-out", logfilePath).start();

InputStream is = v2j.getInputStream();
try(var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is))) {
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Input: " + line);
    }
}

InputStream es = v2j.getErrorStream();
try(var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(es))) {
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + line);
    }
}

v2j.waitFor();
```

Comment: Wow thank you, this work's really fine. I thought the method with `is.available()` was the one to choose, but there seems to be problem.

Comment: @Chris Great! You're welcome! One potential problem with my solution is if the `vcd_converter` would write a lot on the error stream. Since the solution in my answer doesn't read from the error stream until the regular input stream is depleted, it could cause a deadlock. The C++ program would then be waiting for the java program to read the error stream and the java program would be waiting for input on the input stream. I may improve the answer later to fix that.